# C++20 modules in arm-none-eabi-g++

Tags: c++, stm32, c++-modules, stm32cubeide

I'm using [STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html) which includes

arm-none-eabi-g++ (**GNU Tools for STM32** 7-2018-q2-update.20190328-1800) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]

Is there any way to use [C++20 Modules](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules)? C++2a Language Features [table](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) states "no" under "Available in GCC?", but maybe I'm just overlooking something?

[image]

Comment: Not with that version no. C++20 is not released yet, so don't expect it in any release build.  You need an experimental build... i think it's version 10.0 in development. Check godbolt. But it could take a long time before the arm version is there. Why do you need it?

Comment: Even GCC trunk has no support for modules, there is a *highly* experimental branch you can build yourself to try it, but nothing advanced enough for production

Comment: I see.. No true need, just got a project small enough with a deadline far enough that I thought I could play with modules.

Comment: @Xpector I do not think that the Cortex ARM projects will benefit from it. Even big projects build in 2-4 minutes from the clean. 10% does not make any difference.

Comment: Worth mentioning that compile time improvements have been measured at 10x not 10%, which is significant. Although I agree not huge in terms of the final compile time change. But there are many more benefits than just compile times.